# How to describe a previously crumpled but now 'flat' sheet of paper that has been crumpled before?

Tags: single-word-requests

How do you describe the state of a now-flat sheet of paper that has previously been crumpled?

Should I just use *crumpled* as in, "The paper is crumpled" (even though it's not in a crumpled ball shape: it's flat with lines on it that have formed from it's being crumpled previously)?

Comment: "The sheet has been crumpled (but no longer is)."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are looking for [*wrinkled*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wrinkle):

> **wrin·kle**, noun 
>   1. a small furrow or crease in the skin, especially of the face, as from aging or frowning. 
>   2. a temporary slight ridge or furrow on a surface, due to contraction, folding, crushing, or the like.

The second meaning above describes uncrumpled paper perfectly:

> I flattened the page out but it was still wrinkled.

Comment: Also **creased**.

Comment: To my ear, a _creased_ sheet of paper would be one that had been neatly folded (e.g. a sheet of letter paper folded to fit into a "business envelope") and has now been _unfolded_ and still shows the creases. A wrinkled sheet has many tiny creases instead of one or two large ones.

Answer (score 5):

*[Uncrumpled](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/uncrumple)*,  participle of *[uncrumple](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/uncrumple)* (“To return something which has been crumpled, closer to its original state”), may be a good choice.  Wiktionary example sentences include:

> I took the wadded up letter from the trash and carefully uncrumpled it.
>   As the newspaper uncrumpled, the picture on the frontpage become recognizable.

Answer (score 0):

The word 'scrunched, i.e. "crumpled up", comes to mind (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scrunch)

This is definitely used in England. However, I don't think placing the prefix **-un** (unscrunched) works to smooth out the crumpled up paper.